bitbake-layers hangs starting server
I'm fairly new to building yocto, but I have built a couple and I'm learning how the environment is put together.
I've built a docker container for builds, but I keep running into issues with bitbake-layers
If I try to create, add, or show layers all I see is this:
$ bitbake-layers show-layers
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...

... and that's it.
Through other searches people say "look at bitbake-cookerdaemon.log to see why it's hanging"
Okay...
-rw-rw-r--  1 username group    0 Sep 11 12:14 bitbake-cookerdaemon.log
Looks pretty useful.  After I kill the process I get an exception and the log is flushed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1622, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()

61 16:14:09.189081 --- Starting bitbake server pid 61 at 2024-09-11 16:14:09.189036 ---
61 16:14:09.190818 Started bitbake server pid 61
61 16:14:09.191145 Entering server connection loop
61 16:14:09.191199 Lockfile is: /home/username/myir/myir_build/bitbake.lock
Socket is /home/username/myir/myir_build/bitbake.sock (True)
61 16:14:09.191966 Accepting [<socket.socket fd=6, family=1, type=1, proto=0, laddr=bitbake.sock>] ([])
61 16:14:09.192875 Processing Client
61 16:14:09.192947 Connecting Client
61 16:14:09.193583 Running command ['setFeatures', [2, 1]]
61 16:14:09.193656 Sending reply (None, None)
61 16:14:09.193780 Command Completed (socket: True)
61 16:14:09.194723 Running command ['updateConfig', ... ]
61 16:14:09.203470 Sending reply (None, 'bb.BBHandledException()\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/username/myir/myir_build/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 90, in runCommand\n    result = command_method(self, commandline)\n             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File "/home/username/myir/myir_build/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 290, in updateConfig\n    command.cooker.updateConfigOpts(options, environment, cmdline)\n  File "/home/username/myir/myir_build/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 466, in updateConfigOpts\n    self.reset()\n  File "/home/username/myir/myir_build/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 1739, in reset\n    self.initConfigurationData()\n  File "/home/username/myir/myir_build/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 282, in initConfigurationData\n    self.databuilder.parseBaseConfiguration()\n  File "/home/username/myir/myir_build/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 268, in parseBaseConfiguration\n    self.data = self.parseConfigurationFiles(self.prefiles, self.postfiles)\n                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File "/home/username/myir/myir_build/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 468, in parseConfigurationFiles\n    bb.fatal(msg)\n  File "/home/username/myir/myir_build/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 170, in fatal\n    raise BBHandledException()\nbb.BBHandledException\n')
61 16:14:09.203591 Command Completed (socket: True)
61 16:15:34.828883 Processing Client
61 16:15:34.829026 Disconnecting Client (socket: True)
61 16:15:34.829217 No timeout, exiting.
61 16:15:34.929608 Exiting (socket: True)
61 16:15:34.930370 Exiting as we could obtain the lock
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/username/myir/myir_build/bitbake-cookerdaemon.log' mode='a+' encoding='UTF-8'>


I had same issue. In my case this was missing packages in the system. Trying bitbake core-image-minimal gave me better diagnostics (sorry, I didn't copy the exact output).
I installed the missing packages. In my case it was # apt install chrpath diffstat lz4. Then bitbake-layers started to work.
